# Selenium Screenshots save to Database in python

Tags: python, database, selenium, selenium-webdriver, screenshot

When taking web screenshots using selenium web driver, it saved PNG screenshots correctly. So, is there a way to stored these PNG screenshots in database directly? currently I used below code

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/Users/admin/Desktop/chromedriver.exe', options=options)

driver.get(response.url)

S = lambda X: driver.execute_script('return document.body.parentNode.scroll'+X)
driver.set_window_size(S('Width'),S('Height')) # May need manual adjustment                                                                                                                
driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').screenshot('./images/sample.png')
```

Comment: What kind of database? You can save it as a Blob.